# Preventing cells which have changed colors from changing colors again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a sort-of clickable grid. Whenever I click on a blank cell, it should change to either black or white. The next cell that I click should be the other color (if the first cell I click is white, the next cell I click should be black and vice versa). I got this done but if I have clicked on a cell already, it changes the color again which should not happen.

This is the code I have so far:

```js
var white=true;
function generateGrid( rows, cols ) {
    var grid = "<table>";
    for ( row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) {
        grid += "<tr>"; 
        for ( col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) {      
            grid += "<td></td>";
        }
        grid += "</tr>"; 
    }
    return grid;
}

$( "#tableContainer" ).append( generateGrid( 5, 5) );

$( "td" ).click(function() {
    var index = $( "td" ).index( this );
    var row = Math.floor( ( index ) / 5) + 1;
    var col = ( index % 5 ) + 1;
    if (white==true){
       $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'white' );
       white=false
    }
    else if (white==false){
       $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'black' );
       white=true;
    }
});
```

```css
html{
    background-color:blue;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of whether the element has been clicked. One way to do this is using `.data()`:

```
$("td").click(function() {
    var $td = $(this);
    if ($td.data('clicked')) 
        return;

    $td.data('clicked', true);

    $td.css('background-color', white ? 'white' : 'black');
    white = !white;

});
```

Answer (score 1):

lets mark it with a CSS class

```js
var white=true;
function generateGrid( rows, cols ) {
    var grid = "<table>";
    for ( row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) {
        grid += "<tr>"; 
        for ( col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) {      
            grid += "<td></td>";
        }
        grid += "</tr>"; 
    }
    return grid;
}

$( "#tableContainer" ).append( generateGrid( 5, 5) );

$( "td" ).click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('played')) {
      // already played
      return; // bail
    }
    $(this).addClass('played');

    var index = $( "td" ).index( this );
    var row = Math.floor( ( index ) / 5) + 1;
    var col = ( index % 5 ) + 1;
    if (white==true){
       $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'white' );
       white=false
    }
    else if (white==false){
       $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'black' );
       white=true;
    }
});
```

```css
html{
    background-color:blue;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```